# Get the random value inside for loop

Tags: java, android, arrays, for-loop

What I'm doing here is trying to generate a number and see whether it is the same as a number in the array. If it is same, the system will regenerate until the number is unique.

```
Random randomno = new Random();
int r = randomno.nextInt(3);

TextView randomnumber = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TVRno);

int[] arr = new int[2];
arr[0] = 0;
arr[1] = 2;

for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    if(r == arr[i]){
        z = randomno.nextInt(3);
        i = 0;
    }
}

randomnumber.setText("" + z);
```

But in the end I could not print the variable `z` in the `for` loop. How do I print the variable `z`? Am I using the wrong method to do this?

Comment: Do you mean printing to the console?

Comment: @Russiancold Im printing it in an Android emulator

Comment: Hi, if u guys wanna -1 for the question, don't just simply click  -1. Do let me know what's wrong with the question so I can improve next time :D.

Comment: Read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable `z` here is out of scope. It's what's called a *block variable* and it can only be accessed from within the loop. To access it outside, it needs to be declared outside of that loop:

```
Random randomno = new Random();

int r = randomno.nextInt(3);

TextView randomnumber = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TVRno);

int[] arr = new int[2];

arr[0] = 0;

arr[1] = 2;

int z = 0;

            for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
                if(r == arr[i]){
                    z = randomno.nextInt(3);
                    i = 0;
                }
            }
randomnumber.setText("" + z);
```

Looking again, it doesn't seem that you EVER initialized `z`, inside or out. Was your code crashing? If so, that's why.

Side note: You can initialize that array like this: `int arr = new int[] {0,20};`

Comment: If r is 0 you have an infinite loop.

Comment: Even if i declare the variable z outside the loop, it shows it might not have been initialize.

Comment: @jj I forgot about that, try setting it up with a value: `int z = 0;`

Comment: @JJ___ That's ma'am to you :)